# How do I create a Title & Alt tag array for my image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an image gallery where the images are numbered in ascending order  (1-15 per gallery page, & I have about 120 images total). Helpful Stackflow members Rituraj & MarsOne have helped me with the code, because I wanted to reduce the HTML redundancy in my page. The code looks like this now:

```
var str='';
var maxP=15;
var myTitle=new Array(); 
myTitle[1]="Title 1";       
myTitle[2]="Title 2";
myTitle[3]="Title 3";

for(var i=1;i<=maxP;i++)
{ 
str+='<li><a href="images/work/id'+i+'.jpg " rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Title '+i+'"><img src="images/work/idtn'+i+'.jpg " width="100" height="100" alt="Alt Tag Value '+i+'" /></a></li>';
}
```

I would really like the Title & Alt tags to reflect a different value per `id(number).jpg`, so id1.jpg has its own unique alt & title tags, as does `id2.jpg, id3.jpg` & so on. I've tried doing this with `new Array`, but I've no idea is this is the correct way to do it. Also apparently I can't just do:

`'+myTitle['+i+']+'`

Because then nothing loads. I think I also have redundant values for some Title tags, so it might be best to use an array. Thank you so much in advance, I have tried figuring this out on my own, but I could really use some help. A link to a website/reference for doing this will help, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your index is equal to the value of `i`, not to the string literal `'+i+'`.

You need `i` not `'+i+'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=1;i<=maxP;i++)
{ 
str+='<li><a href="images/work/id'+i+'.jpg " rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Title '+myTitle[i]+'"><img src="images/work/idtn'+i+'.jpg " width="100" height="100" alt="Alt Tag Value '+myTitle[i]+'" /></a></li>';
}
```

you don't need the '+i+', all you need is i which will be the index of the array. So myTitle[i] will get the title for item i in the array.

Comment: don't need id in image name:

`images/work/id'+myTitle[i]+'.jpg`
to 
`images/work/'+myTitle[i]+'.jpg`

Comment: also you you changed the href not src.